# Passing images and stylish text to Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, modal-dialog

I think my problem is a little complicated . I use Laravel as my framework and have a HTML table that shows the posts list and has some `TD` (like post_title , post_content ,post_author ,...) . each post_title is an `<a>` tag that when clicked, a modal is opened and has some text field (to show title, authorName, publishedDate ...) and a textarea (to show the post content) .

My first problem was passing these elements to modal (after Many searches I finally found the solution) and my current problem is that with this way of passing variables I just can show the post content as long as it is just simple text . If the text has some style (bold ,italic ..) I can't pass it to modal . It's because for some quotation marks for tags like `<b>ggg</b>`...any idea about that?

This is the way I pass elements :

```
 <td class="td4">    <!--the td that shows title and is a link to open modal-->
         <!--===================================================modal-->
         <a href="#myModal" class="saha" data-title="<?php echo $article->title; ?>" data-body="<?php echo $article->body; ?>" id="<?php echo $article->id; ?>"  data-toggle="modal">{{$article->title}}</a>
```

and my javascript:

```
 $('a.saha').click(function(e){
 var essay_id = $(this).attr('id');
 var title= $(this).data('title');
 var body = $(this).data('body');
 $("#article_id").val(essay_id);
 $("#onvan").val(title);
 tinymce.editors[0].setContent(body);///my textarea
});
```

when I have just simple text as body, it shows title (the  tag) something like this : [post1](http://www.google.com)
but when I have styled text or image in my body it shows some thing like :

```
an article the name <b "id="18" data-toggle="modal"..
```

any help? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the HTML so it doesn't mess with things using the [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) function.

So

```
<a title="{{ htmlspecialchars($article->title) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

ok it works finally ... :)

I should just write :

```
data-body="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($article->body) ;?>"
```

instesd of :

```
data-body="<?php echo $article->body; ?>"
```